# JavaFX unreadable property

Tags: java, javafx, controller

In my task I need to display id of Cars in my table. I saw possible solution with get and set but it doesnt work. I have 2 classes CarEntity and Cars.

CarEntity class:

```
public abstract class CarEntity implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public CarEntity (Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name= name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

//+ get and set for name

Class Cars extend CarEntity and I have no problem with nameOfCar in my table.

```
This is Controller:

 List<Cars> listOfCars;
    @FXML
    private TextField idOfCar;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameOfCar;
    @FXML private  TableColumn <Cars, Long> colIfOfCar;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Cars, String> colNameofCar;
```

In  initialize I have:;

```
    colIfOfCar.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));

    colNameofCar.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

Error I get:

> WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'idOfCar' in PropertyValueFactory:
> javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@43a5f6f with provided
> class type: class  main.carstore.model.Cars
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read from unreadable property
> idOfCar

Comment: Are you *certain* that your code contains `new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")` and not `new PropertyValueFactory<>("idOfCar")`?  It’s best to avoid PropertyValueFactory entirely, since reflection mistakes cannot be caught at compile time;  a better option is to add property accessors to your CarEntity class, like most standard JavaFX classes have, then use them to write your own cell value factory expressions.

Comment: [mcve] please .. your snippet doesn't fit the error message as already pointed out by @VGR ..

Comment: Your table model needs to be composed of Properties as fields, not primitive types. The need to be implemented as JavaFX Beans to use PropertyValueFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation it is looking for a method such as `public Property<String> variableProperty()` in the entity class in your case car so one method would be
`public Property<String> nameProperty(){return name;}`

Answer (score -3):

In Controller Id should only be Id not idOfSomething

**@FXML
private TextField **id****

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with the error you posted in the question